# learning rate in reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Does anyone know how to get the learning rate from participant data?

I'm computing all the expected values for all trials (=200)

$$V_t(S) = V_{t-1}(S)+ \alpha \cdot \text{error }_t $$

$$(\text{error }_t = R_t − V_{t-1}(S))$$

and then computing alpha at each trial using

$$\alpha= (V_t(S)  - V_{t-1}(S) )/ \text{error }_t$$

but it seems not the right way!

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't seem like the right way? If you provide clear information on what's wrong, its easier for people to help you.

Comment: So I initialised all the values in the first iteration.. computed the V(S)t and then I used all the V(S)t already computed to computed alpha trial-by-trial.. first, I really don't know if it is the right way of proceeding ..second I've got a alpha vector of all 1 and NaN values...

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the question I hope my answer helps you. From what I understand you want to fit a RL model to participant's data who did a decision making task. The whole process of fitting RL models to data is described in great detail in [Trial by Trial analysis using RL](http://www.princeton.edu/~ndaw/d10.pdf) by Nathaniel Daw.

Briefly, what you observe (your data) is just actions and rewards at every time step. If the participant is using a RL model you should expect to update the values of his actions according to:

$Q_t(a_t)=Q_t(a_{t-1})+\alpha\cdot (r_t-Q_t(a_{t-1}))$

and action selection with the Boltzmann function:

$p(a_{t}|s_{t})=\frac{e^{\beta Q(s_{t},a_{t})}}{\sum_{a'}e^{\beta Q(s_{t},a')}}$

We prefer to use a stochastic policy as it simulates better human choices and it is straightforward to create a likelihood function. The likelihood function would be the product of all the probabilities $p(a_t|s_t)$. The model parameters are $[{\alpha,\beta}]$ and these can be inferred by standard Maximum Likelihood techniques.

Finally, our hypothesis (=model) can be summarized as: A subject generates a sequence of (observed) actions. To generate these actions we assumed that uses a RL model with some parameters. We want to fit the model to the data to infer these parameters and test the suitability of the model and the cognitive/psychological links of the values of the parameters.